# Left justify footnotes that appear centered

Tags: latex, footnotes

How do I justifying footnotes that appear centered in latex.  I've tried using \justifyleft but the label that identified the footnote was still centered.

```
\documentclass[sigconf,screen,pagebackref]{article}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{times,amsmath,epsfig,graphicx,amssymb,multirow,subfig}
\usepackage{mathtools, cuted}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{url}



\begin{document}


    \begin{algorithm}[!phb]
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}


            My algorithm step 1\footnote{Dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.}

            My algorithm step 2.\footnote{Dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.}
            \hrule
        \end{minipage}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Correction to the first line:

\documentclass[sigconf,screen,pagebackref]{acmart}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Please edit your post with the correction you have commented _ Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Centred footnotes are a design decision of the class you are using. If you don't want them centred

- use another document class
- overwrite the design decisions made by the class, but don't plan to submit this paper somewhere that requires the acmart style

---

```
\documentclass[sigconf,screen,pagebackref]{acmart}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{times,amsmath,epsfig,graphicx,amssymb,multirow,subfig}
\usepackage{mathtools, cuted}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{url}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@mpfootnotetext#1{%
  \global\setbox\@mpfootins\vbox{%
    \unvbox\@mpfootins
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \hsize\columnwidth
    \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel
         {\csname p@mpfootnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}%
    \color@begingroup%\centering
      \@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}


    \begin{algorithm}[!phb]
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}


            My algorithm step 1\footnote{Dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.}

            My algorithm step 2.\footnote{Dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.}
            \hrule
        \end{minipage}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```